# Return multiple results depending on Quantity field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, resultset

I have the following table of records:

```
Product     |    Colour  |   Quantity
---------------------------------------
Product A   |    Blue    |          1
Product A   |    Red     |          2
Product B   |    Green   |          1
```

How can I write a query to return the following?:

```
Product     |    Colour
---------------------------
Product A   |    Blue
Product A   |    Red
Product A   |    Red
Product B   |    Green
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH    numbers (rn) AS
        (
        SELECT  MAX(quantity)
        FROM    product
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  rn - 1
        FROM    numbers
        WHERE   rn > 1
        )
SELECT  p.*
FROM    product p
JOIN    numbers n
ON      p.quantity >= n.rn
```

Comment: This seems to return the opposite for me. 2 results where the quantity is 1, and 1 result where the quantity is 2. Any ideas?

Comment: @Curt: sure, just change the sign in the `ON` clause. See the post update.

Comment: This is brilliant. Took me a while to work out how it works exactly, but now I know, think its great solution. Cheers.